# Hide elements when width change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have question because I'm try hide menu when window width is more than 766px. This is my code but not work

HTML

```
<div class="menu">
    <div class="burger-menu">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
    </div>
    <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="#about-me">O mnie</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Prace</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Certyfikty</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Cennik</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Kontakt</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JQuery

```
//Burger menu

$('.burger-menu').click(function(){

  $(this).toggleClass('open');

});

//Menu list

$('.burger-menu').click(function(){
    $('.submenu').slideToggle();    
});


if($(window).width() > 766){
    $('.submenu').hide();
}else {
    console.log('halo');
};
```

Everything works but when I click burger and menu slide for example on 677px and then resize window to more than 766px menu still there. Thanks for every help

Comment: use resize event [link](https://api.jquery.com/resize/)

Comment: Can you not use CSS? like so... `@media screen and (min-width: 767px){.class {display:none}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Problem:-***

Window width checking code not running every-time when you are resizing your window.

***Solution:-***

Use  [jQuery resize()](https://api.jquery.com/resize/)  like below:-

```
$(window).resize(function(){
  if($(window).width() > 766){
    $('.submenu').hide();
  }else{
    console.log('halo');
   //add $('.submenu').show(); to show menu
  }
});
```

Note:- rest of the code is Ok.

Comment: @Bartas, else part should have $('.submenu').show(), otherwise , it will only hide and not show , if width < 766px

Answer (score 2):

You could use CSS media queries, but since you want jQuery... On window resize, you need to check the width of the window. With your code, it's only running once.

```
$('.burger-menu').click(function(){

  $(this).toggleClass('open');

});


//Menu list

$('.burger-menu').click(function(){
    $('.submenu').slideToggle();    
});


 $(window).resize(function(){
     if($(window).width() > 766){
        $('.submenu').hide();
     }else {
         console.log('halo');
     };
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve expected result, use below **CSS**

```
@media (min-width: 766px) {
  .submenu {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/yXRVOe

Other option **Using Jquery**, make below changes to work on resize and on page load

1. Check the screen width on load and if width is more than 766px , hide .submenu
2. On window resize, show the .submenu if the screen width is less than 766px and hide , if more than 766px

   Use Jquery, follow below steps

   if($(window).width() > 766){
                   $('.submenu').hide();
                 }

   $(window).resize(function(){
          if($(window).width() > 766){
                   $('.submenu').hide();
                 }
                 else {
                    $('.submenu').show();// add else condition to show if condition faile
                   console.log('halo');
                 };
       });

https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/vZVyyz

Comment: Thanks! I try this to :)

Answer (score 0):

you should call the resize function in jquery
    //the function to hide the div
    function hideDiv(){

```
if ($(window).width() < 1024) {

        $("#floatdiv").fadeOut("slow");

}else{

    $("#floatdiv").fadeIn("slow");

}

}

//run on document load and on window resize
$(document).ready(function () {

//on load
hideDiv();

//on resize
$(window).resize(function(){
    hideDiv();
  });

});
```

or you can do it with css media query :

```
   /* always assume on smaller screen first */

 #floatdiv {
  display:none;
 }

/* if screen size gets wider than 1024 */

 @media screen and (min-width:1024px){
    #floatdiv {
      display:block;
  } 
 }
```